# Assigning more than one column to a collection using BULK COLLECT

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am not sure why I am getting this error with this code, Please help me with debugging this code Thanks in advance.

```
declare
type emp_t is table of employees%rowtype
index by pls_integer;
rec   emp_t;
begin
  select employee_id,salary,manager_id bulk collect into rec
  from employees where rownum <100;

 forall i in 1..rec.last
    update employees
    set salary=salary+10
    where employee_id=rec(i).employee_id;

end;

ORA-06550: line 7, column 3:
PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I have changed the code to the below format but it's still giving me "expression is of wrong type error"

```
declare 
type emp_t is table of employees%rowtype
index by pls_integer;
rec   emp_t;

begin
for val in (
  select employee_id,salary,manager_id 
  from employees where rownum <100)

  loop
      rec:=val;

  end loop;

 forall i in 1..rec.last
    update employees
    set salary=salary+10
    where employee_id=rec(i).employee_id;

end;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use either one or the other:

```
  TYPE emp_t IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  --                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  --                  each record is "one row" of table `employees`

  ...

  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO rec FROM employees WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
  --     ^
  --   get all columns for each row
```

*Or*

```
  TYPE emp_rec IS RECORD (
    employee_id employees.employee_id%TYPE,
    salary employees.salary%TYPE,
    manager_id employees.manager_id%TYPE
  );
  TYPE emp_t IS TABLE OF emp_rec
  --                     ^^^^^^^
  --               each record only contains the necessary fields

  ...

  SELECT employee_id,salary,manager_id BULK COLLECT INTO rec FROM employees WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
  --     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  --       get only what we need (and in that particular order)
```

Very probably you are looking for the second form. Using a [custom type for the `RECORD`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/PLS23/ch4.htm#user-def%20recs) you are trying to bulk collect. Please notice the use of [`%TYPE` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/type_attribute.htm) in the record declaration. That's an alias to the type of each column.

Comment: Can you please explain why it's getting error even after changing the code to the second form.

Comment: @Asfakul I didn't try it, but at first sight this is the same issue: you select a _subset_ of the columns, but `rec` is still declared as a "full row" (using %ROWTYPE). Simply said: if you use `%ROWTYPE`, you should `SELECT *`. Otherwise, you need a custom record type.

Comment: But in case of cursor I can declare a rowtype variable and then fetch subset of columns into that variable. I guess it's not permissible in collection

Comment: @Asfakul Sorry, my previous comment was somehow oversimplified. `table%ROWTYPE` is a record corresponding to a "full" table row. So beg for a `SELECT *`. But `cursor%ROWTYPE` is a row corresponding to the virtual table produced by the `SELECT x,y,z,whatever`  statement. But maybe that would call for _an other question_ ?

Comment: I know this is a side-question, but how could one employ this technique with the DELETE clause? Is it even possible to retrieve multiple columns from the deleted rows using a similar technique?

Answer (score 0):

`emp_t`  is declared as `ROWTYPE`, that includes all the columns, 

but while retrieving records your are retrieving only `employee_id,salary,manager_id`, 

that could be the reason of your error.

Try this :

```
declare
type emp_t is table of employees%rowtype
index by pls_integer;
rec   emp_t;
begin
  select employee_id,salary,manager_id bulk collect into rec
  from employees where rownum <100;

 forall i in 1..rec.last
    update employees
    set salary=salary+10
    where employee_id=rec(i).employee_id;

end;
```

The second one seem to have other issues like TYPE difference VAR and REC