# JSON to SQL objects

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE json_record_type
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    id    NUMBER,
    name  VARCHAR2(50),
    ` age NUMBER );
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE json_table_type
AS
  TABLE OF json_record_type;
  ;
  DECLARE
    json_data CLOB := '{ "data": [ {"id": 1, "name": "John", "age": 30}, {"id": 2, "name": "Alice", "age": 25} ] }';
    json_obj json_table_type;
  BEGIN
    SELECT * BULK COLLECT
    INTO json_obj
    FROM JSON_TABLE(json_data, '$.data[*]' COLUMNS ( ID NUMBER PATH '$.id', name VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.name', age NUMBER PATH '$.age' ) );
    FOR i IN 1..json_obj.COUNT
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID: ' || json_obj(i).id || ', Name: ' || json_obj(i).name || ', Age: ' || json_obj(i).age);
    END LOOP;
  END;
  '
```

Comment: when i execute the test block i m getting Error report:
ORA-06550: line 12, column 3:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Comment: Is the hyphen at the end in your code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26087449/2778710. You cannot bulk collect multiple columns into SQL collection.

Comment: @astentx Yes, you can. The issue is you can't use '*' to refer to multiple columns. It only works if there is only 1 column. That's even what your link says.

Comment: @redwards No, you cannot. As I wrote, you cannot bulk collect multiple columns into object table (SQL collection), because it is a collection of scalars (of object type). But if you define your type as PL/SQL **record** type (either implicitly inheriting via `%rowtype` or explicitly), then Oracle is possible to call **record** constructor before bulk collection to construct a desired record even with star (\*) as select list. See https://dbfiddle.uk/l_NWrszB

Comment: @astentx  Yes! Thanks. I was incorrectly assuming the record part.  But it was just an object.  And thanks for the reminder where the ora-friendly dbfiddle was.
Removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given your types (without the random additional characters):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE json_record_type AS OBJECT(
  id    NUMBER,
  name  VARCHAR2(50),
  age   NUMBER
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE json_table_type AS TABLE OF json_record_type;
```

Bulk collect the instances of the object (containing the values) into the collection:

```sql
DECLARE
  json_data CLOB := '{ "data": [ {"id": 1, "name": "John", "age": 30}, {"id": 2, "name": "Alice", "age": 25} ] }';
  json_obj json_table_type;
BEGIN
  SELECT json_record_type(id, name, age)
  BULK COLLECT INTO json_obj
  FROM   JSON_TABLE(
           json_data,
           '$.data[*]'
           COLUMNS (
             ID   NUMBER       PATH '$.id',
             name VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.name',
             age  NUMBER       PATH '$.age'
           )
         );

  FOR i IN 1..json_obj.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      'ID: ' || json_obj(i).id
      || ', Name: ' || json_obj(i).name
      || ', Age: ' || json_obj(i).age
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID: 1, Name: John, Age: 30
> ID: 2, Name: Alice, Age: 25
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zYVCwkU3)